# What is the correlation between ECMAScript 5 and JavaScript 1.8.5 in terms of language features?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, ecmascript-5

I've been reading up on Mozilla's continuing development of JavaScript, up through version 1.8.5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript.

My question is: What is the correlation between JavaScript 1.8.5+ and ECMAScript 5+ in terms of language features? Any chance Mozilla's new JavaScript features (like generators, array comprehensions, etc.) will become part of ECMAScript?

I just want to get a handle on whether it's worth learning JavaScript 1.8.5 features (and working to shim them into non-supporting browsers) or whether I should forget JS 1.8.5 and focus on learning/shimming the new ECMAScript 5 features.

FYI: Mozilla talks about how they're planning to bring JavaScript into compliance with ECMAScript 5 here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla

Comment: I for one don't want the pythonisation that mozilla is bringing.

Comment: My big question is when Javascript is finally going to be able to handle Unicode in its regexes, at least up to [Level 1 compliance with UTS#18: “Basic Unicode Support”](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support).  It’s tantamount to useless in today’s post-ASCII world without it.

Comment: Me neither, I think some of the features are cool, but it's overkill, pythonization is a good way to put it. The only thing I want is the ability to declare types if I chose to (like ActionScript)

Comment: @JuanMendes let's not bring in strict typing please! Imagine if jQuery enforced strict typing internally. We would all have to start using it. It's not an optional thing with those popular 3rd party libraries we rely on.

Comment: @Raynos I'm an OO programmer, strict typing is very helpful to me. I am writing thick clients with 30, 50 classes per page. Strict typing can catch many of the bugs before I test the page manually or in unit testing. jQuery would probably not use strict typing in most of its functions.

Comment: @JuanMendes use `instanceof` asserts & checks. Alternatively your bringing too much class-typed OO over into javascript. I see there being no need for strict typing, just a need for a different type of programming that suits javascript. JavaScript is too easy to bend and abuse with the wrong paradigm.

Comment: @Raynos: Completely disagree: I'm not going to add asserts and `instanceof` to every function. That's what a language is for. If you like procedural dynamic code, I like OO typed code. To each his own. I do not know of a single person that writes widget driven desktop-like web-apps that doesn't use OO. Maybe, you're the first? For web pages, progressive enhancement and simple web apps, yeah, it's overkill. But when you are dealing with apps where JS renders 100% of the HTML, OO just helps your organize and maintain code.

Comment: @JuanMendes I use prototyped OO and functional code. I don't write procedural code. I just never have a use for type checking. I write a development version of my code with debugging statements and tests all over the place, then get a compiler to strip it out. It also helps more then hinders as the high level design stays consistant.

Comment: OO is not synonymous with static typing.  There are plenty of dynamically typed OO languages around, and always have been.

Comment: @tchrist this is one of them.

Comment: @Raynos: The thing is most people confuse strict typing with static typing.  Most dynamically typed languages are also strictly typed; they're just not statically typed.  The B&D people get this confused a lot.

Comment: @tchrist B&D, what do you mean?

Comment: @Raynos: Bondage and discipline; you know, straitjacket programming. :) A better way to talk about these things might be compile-time typing vs run-time typing.  Both can be and indeed usually are strict.  The question comes down to when you learn of a type mismatch, not whether you learn of it.

Comment: @tchrist: Until JavaScript supports Unicode regex categories, you can use Steven Levithan's excellent Unicode plugin for his XRegExp library: http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Comment: @Raynos: Last argument, I promise. I use jsdoc with google closure compiler to add type checking during the compilation phase. I'm just saying it would be nice not to need a build step, to have a standard way to create a class, rather than a separate way per lib that we have now. I probably misspoke when I agreed with you that I wanted static typing, what I would like the most is for the compiler to tell me (when I chose to) that I've used a property/method that is not present for an object, or when I pass something in to a function that is not of the right type? Don't u encounter those bugs?

Comment: @JuanMendes. Psh use NaturalDocs it's better. Seriously though closure compiler is a good tool to add compile level type checking without messing with the underlying javascript. If the closure compiler allowed for contracts I would use it every day.

Comment: @Raynos: My base lib is Ext-JS, and all my widgets extend their classes (which use jsdoc) so I can't really use a different doc format unless I want to lose all the inherited information from my docs.

Comment: @JuanMendes Widgets? Widgets?! Any respectable hand renders his GUI on the canvas.

Comment: @Raynos: Real programmers code using butterflies http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: @JuanMendes Seriously, hand-crafted GUI's on the canvas are beautiful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript 1.8.5 is Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript with added features. It's a superset of the ECMAScript specification (and of current implementations like IE, Chrome and Opera). Mozilla pushes for the features it adds to its own browser, they may or may not make it into ECMA. Note that Mozilla is a member of the W3C and has some say, but my guess is that most features won't make it.

**Bottom Line** Don't use it unless you're coding something specific to firefox, FF extensions, XUL apps, Rhino (Added Rhino thanks to @Raynos)

Comment: Or Rhino! Or anything else that runs on the mozilla JavaScript interpretor.

Comment: That's cool. I actually thought Rhino was stuck with a much older version of JavaScript, but yeah, you can even choose the version to use, it supports up to 1.7 currently https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer.

Answer (score 3):

Defiantly focus on ES5. The issue with 1.7 & 1.8 features is that they change the syntax of the language so you can't shim them into other code.

You can emulate all the properties of the Object with ES5 but you can't emulate the `let` keyword. In other browsers the various expression are just not valid javascript.

You must distinquish between making addition to native code which is what most of ES5 is doing and changing the syntax of javascript which is what 1.7 & 1.8 are doing.

There is a use for 1.7 & 1.8 which is to develop for the RHINO platform. But for browser javascript stick to the spec.

Admittedly the multiple value returns is a pretty neat feature. Having an array assignment like that would be nice

```
function() f {
     return [1,2,3];
}

[a,b,c] = f()
```

But the other features are quite major changes to the syntax and you just can't push them through ecmascript they just won't deal with it. Small changes like above you might be able to get into ES6 but your going to have to wait at least a year.

So realistically don't expect the learning to pay off for a year or two if at all. Most likely it won't pay off. Do look at libraries such as [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) which can define common functional utility methods for you.

Comment: It's possible to alter the syntax of the language, by introducing a parser/generator that compiles code down to normal JavaScript. See CoffeeScript - http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/. This would be a valid (although very time-consuming) method of shimming JS 1.8.5 support.

Comment: @RoyTinker It's possible to script in C. I think ECMAScript should support C. I have a C to JavaScript compiler.

Comment: @tchrist, your comments are off-topic, the question is not about regex

Comment: @Juan, the question is about the connection between two standards, including talk of new ones. It seems natural to ask whether either of those two new standards discussed happens to address a problem.

Comment: @tchrist I guess, but there is no talk of supporting Unicode in Mozilla's JS or ECMAScript yet, is there? Raynos didn't even mention regex in his answer.

Comment: @Juan what's all the fuss about? Comments are off topic all the time, and at least it wasn't an answer. It was also more valuable than both our comments discussing it ;)

Comment: @Box9: I think it’s a strict-typing problem. :)

Comment: @Box: Sorry, y'all, didn't mean to fuss. I still don't see any correlation to the question. UTF-8 RegeEx support is a feature that many of us would like, does not address the correlation between JavaScript 1.8 and ECMAScript5

Comment: Just a note, your example of destructuring assignment is valid ES6, so they converged on this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think ECMAScript is the "standard", like a blueprint, and javascript is the actual language it is based off of.  Kind of like how w3c has their standards and then people make (or don't) make rendering engines based off it.

So basically to answer your question, look at ECMAScript to see what the consensus is, how javascript is "supposed" to work, but you should focus on javascript, because that's what you will actually be coding with.